# Using https://etherchain.org API

Tags: python, difficulty, external-api

When I request https://etherchain.org/api/difficulty using python 3.6 I get HTTPError: Forbidden. Does anyone know the solution?

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

r_difficulty_eth = 
urlopen('https://etherchain.org/api/difficulty').read().decode('UTF-8')

difficulty_eth_data = json.loads(r_difficulty_eth)
```

Comment: this question its should be asked in python community

Comment: Based on https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/487/at-what-point-are-mining-questions-off-topic, I _think_ this is on-topic for this community because the code above actually works for other servers, so it's an Ethereum-(ish) specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Etherchain is protected by [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com). It tries to prevent automated requests to the system. Which seems silly for an API... Anyway, the way around it is to make Python act as though it's a regular web browser in the `User-Agent` request header.

```
import json
import urllib.request

request = urllib.request.Request(url='https://etherchain.org/api/difficulty', 
                             data=None,
                             headers={
                                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.4'
                            })

r_difficulty_eth = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read().decode('UTF-8')
difficulty_eth_data = json.loads(r_difficulty_eth)
```